# Relationships in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

when the admin select a category in `<select></select>` i want to get its id for insert it in a question table

table questions:

```
Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('question_text');
            $table->string('type');
            $table->integer('points');
            $table->integer('temps_reponse');

            $table->integer('categories_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('categories_id')->references('id')->on('categories');

            $table->timestamps();

        });
```

table categorie :

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('categorie');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Question Model

```
class Question extends Model
{

    public function categorie()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Categorie::class, 'categories_id');
    }
}
```

Categorie Model

```
class Categorie extends Model
{
    public function question()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Question::class, 'question_id')->withTrashed();
    }
}
```

I am blocked with it for a few hours please any help to solve it

my html

```
<label class="form-label">Choisir la categorie :</label>
                                                <select class="" id="s2example-1" name="categorie">
                                                        <option></option>
                                                    @foreach ($categories as $categorie)
                                                        <option>{{ $categorie->categorie }}</option>
                                                    @endforeach
                                                </select>
```

Comment: Can you add the html you have so far?

Comment: @Quezler here is my html part

Comment: Allright, try: `<option value={{$categorie->id}}>{{ $categorie->categorie }}</option>`

Comment: @Quezler thanks for your help it works very fine

Comment: Sweet, i have added it as an answer to, since it is :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to send the id instead of the string back to the server, supply the value attribute on each option element: `<option value={{$categorie->id}}>{{ $categorie->categorie }}</option>`